# How can I create a popup that displays when a user closes a case within a specific record type?

Tags: visualforce, popup

How can I create a popup that displays when a user attempts to close a case that is a specific record type? There are certain cases that are repeated every month and the existing practice is for agents to close these recurring processes and then clone them so that they can be repeated the following month.

I have little exposure to Visualforce, but from reading a few places, I'm starting with a Page that looks like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
rendered="{Case.RecordType='Recurring_Process'}">
**Need statement to check if Close button is clicked
<script type="text/javascript"> { window.alert("Remember to Clone the Case"); }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific record type, you can create a separate page layout. Then you can create a custom detail page button with title Close Case and the settings as shown in the image below. Remove the standard Close Case button from the page layout and add the custom button to the layout.

```
alert("Remember to Clone the Case");
window.location = "/{!Case.Id}/s?retURL=/{!Case.Id}";
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That worked great. Nice and simple too. Thanks
!